# How to access full email source code in thunderbird message_display_action extension?

Tags: javascript, thunderbird-addon

I am building an extension in Thunderbird with UI element message_display_action for my school project. I am wondering if I can access full email source code from java script file that I am using for building up my html page when pressing on button [my extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTsSw.png). I found a funciton named getFull(messageId) in documentation at https://webextension-api.thunderbird.net/ but I don't understand how to use that function and I don't even know what messageId is. I know it is a integer but I don't know how to get that integer for a specific email. I entered permission (messagesRead) in my manifest file of extension for reading emails but i still don't know how to use that function. I didn't find any examples or tutorials on the internet so if anyone can help me or atleast point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Getting the `id` of the currently displayed message

You should take a look at https://github.com/thundernest/sample-extensions/tree/master/messageDisplay, which is an example how to get the `id` of the currently displayed message from the `messageDisplayAction` using `messageDisplay.getDisplayedMessage()`.

See also https://webextension-api.thunderbird.net/en/latest/messageDisplay.html.

#### `messages.getFull()`

Didn't find a small example using that API. As a hint you should note that this function works on the different MIME parts a mail consists of.

You will not get the complete source of the email that way. To get the raw source you would need to use `messages.getRaw()`. But you should probably not use `getRaw()` unless you really need it, because you would need to handle the complete parsing of the message yourself.